# Sites with hideable announcements/tips

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Does anyone know of any site that uses javascript to generate a tip/message/announcement block that has a 'Hide this' option? Preferably like Stack Overflow where other containers get shifted up when the tip/announcement is hidden. I'm just trying to compile a list of sites using that feature.

Thanks

Comment: Not a programming-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) uses that kind of announcements with it's fundraising campaigns.